# Approach: Modify Complex Data using AOP and Reflection

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, adaptive-design

I have configured my spring Application as below:

```
 // Spring MVC controller
 @Controller
 HelloController {  

   @ResponseBody
   Student getData() {
    return student from database;
    }
 }

public Class Student {

 @Trim(device = "mob", trim=10)
 @Trim(device = "desktop", trim=100)
 String name ;

 Address address;

}

public class Address {

 @Trim(device = "mob", trim=10 )
 @Trim(device = "desktop", trim=100 )
 String addressInfo

 }
```

**Requirements:**

After the `Controller` returns the Student, do modification of Student object and all complex attributes inside it based on the `Annotation`,
 for example if the request was from **mobile trim the student name  to  10**  and so on.

**Approaches I can think of:**

1. Recursively iterate on fields with annotation and modify fields.
        Iteration on class fields every time can be hectic, as the class is complex and can nest up to n levels.
2. Create a List of Annotated fields at server start up and when then iterate on this list and apply changes to the target object.

   I am currently struggling with both approachs. So would like to know whether there exists some prebuilt solutions or design patterns to handle such scenarios.

Comment: How do you know whether to use the mobile or desktop version?  Is it included in the request?  Are you returning XML or JSON?

Comment: We are returning JSON, and the mobile or desktop is in request, will use the `@AfterReturning` AOP to get the request and hence the device

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use AOP on my model objects.  What tools are you using to build the JSON and have you checked if your tool has a hook to customize field output?

Comment: Your first approach seems most appropriate. Note that java 7-, you can't annotate a field with the same annotation more than once. However, you can an annotation that accepts an array of some other type of annotation. For example `@TrimStrategies(strats = {@Trim(...), @Trim(...)})`

Comment: @JohnR, These are not model objects but view objects to be consumed by view layer as json. We are passing the Object as is and relying on Spring-MVC (basically jackson) to get it converted into JSON. So using AOP to modify the object after it is actually created.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Very thanks for the information, would take care of this while actually implementing. Does there exists a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually coded the Reflection based approach and created a library some time back.

It uses reflection to identify annotation on fields and then takes the appropriate action based on the input device.

Here is the link for library
https://github.com/santoshjoshi/Adaptive-Device-Data-Filtering

Comment: I just saw this question now because it was updated. Why did you want to solve it via reflection and not using Spring AOP or AspectJ? I am just asking because you tagged the question with "aop" anyway. This is how I found it. Reflection is slow, tedious and problematic with regard to type safety.

Comment: @kriegaex, Basically AOP was at the second place wrapping all this.At first level considering that there is a complex class containing other classes which can nest up to n levels. the main issue was on the basis of some condition i need to restrict the data. For example if the device is desktop then description instance variable  should only pass 300 words and  50 words if the device is mobile.

Comment: @kriegaex basically approach was to annotate instance variable with annotation and then using reflection recursively iterate on fields with those annotation and modify instance variables.  It would be great to know if this can be better solved using AOP and other techniques.

Comment: If I can avoid reading all your code, I would like to. So can you please explain how and when your trimming occurs? Only when accessing members for printing or transfer? Are the values truncated dynamically or do you really change the object's properties? Please update your own answer with some sample code so as to show how the library is used and what (side?) effects it has. Then I can think about how to create an equivalent solution with AOP.